# How to expand the right-hand side of $\langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\lVert x+\alpha^n y \rVert^2\alpha^n$?

Tags: complex-numbers, normed-spaces, inner-products

If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a complex inner product and if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha^N = 1$ but $\alpha^2 \not = 1$, then show that

$$\langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\lVert x+\alpha^n y \rVert^2\alpha^n$$

where, as usual, $\lVert w \rVert = \langle w, w\rangle^{1/2}$.

Expand the right-hand side
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\lVert x+\alpha^n y \rVert^2\alpha^n 
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\langle x+\alpha^n y, x+\alpha^n y \rangle \alpha^n \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\langle x+\alpha^n y, x+\alpha^n y \rangle \alpha^n \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left( \langle x, x \rangle +(\overline{\alpha})^n \langle x, y \rangle + \alpha^n\langle y, x \rangle + \alpha^n(\overline{\alpha})^n\langle y,y \rangle \right) \alpha^n 
\end{align*}
$$=  \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^n\langle x, x \rangle + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \lvert \alpha\rvert^{2n} \langle x, y \rangle + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^{2n} \langle y, x \rangle + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^n \lvert \alpha\rvert^{2n}\langle y,y \rangle \right )$$

We need to use the fact that $1+\alpha + \alpha^2 + \dots + \alpha^{N-1} = \frac{1-\alpha^N}{1-\alpha}$ but I don't know how to proceed. Any help?

Comment: You have two mistakes. $\alpha^n\langle x,y\rangle$ ought to be $\alpha^n \langle y,x\rangle$, and the coefficient of $\langle y,y\rangle$ is $\alpha^n\cdot \overline{\alpha}^n = \lvert \alpha\rvert^{2n} = 1$. Split the sum into four parts, each of the form $\sum c_n\cdot \langle u,v\rangle$. Use the mentioned fact to conclude that three of the sums are $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree that $\alpha^n\langle x,y\rangle$ should be $\alpha^n \langle y,x\rangle$ and the coefficient of $\langle y, y \rangle$ is $\alpha^n \cdot \overline{\alpha}^n = \lvert \alpha\rvert^{2n}$. Why $\alpha^n\cdot \overline{\alpha}^n = \lvert \alpha\rvert^{2n} = 1$? $\alpha^N=1$ not $\alpha^n = 1$, and is it still true after adding $\mid \cdot \mid$?

Comment: If $\alpha^N = 1$, then it follows that $\lvert \alpha\rvert = 1$ (for example this way: $\alpha^N = 1$ implies $\lvert \alpha\rvert^N = \lvert \alpha^N\rvert = \lvert 1\rvert = 1$, taking the positive $N^{\text{th}}$ root finishes it).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|\alpha|=1$ therefore $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^n=\dfrac{1-\alpha^{N}}{1-\alpha}=0\\\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |\alpha|^{2n}=N\\\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^{2n}=\dfrac{1-\alpha^{2N}}{1-\alpha^2}=0\\\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^n|\alpha|^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^n=0$$

Comment: whats happen if $w=1$ and $w^2=1$?